# Is there a way to simplify regex matching characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a ECMAScript (JavaScript) flavor regex to test the strength of my password based on these criteria:

```
    Characters Used          Password Strength Length
   ABC  abc  123  #$&      WEAK  ...
1   x                      1-5   ...   
2        x                 1-5
3             x            1-7
4                  x       1-5
5   x    x                 1-4   
6   x         x            1-4
7   x              x       1-4
8        x    x            1-4 
9        x         x       1-4       
10            x    x       1-4     
11  x    x    x            1-4           
12  x    x         x       1-3   
13  x        x     x       1-4           
14      x    x     x       1-4  
15  x   x    x     x       1-3
```

So passwords like `2`, `ABCD`, `0123456`, `abCd`, `aA#`, etc. should be marked as weak. Passwords that are longer for the specified combination `012345678`, `aA1#`, etc. should not.

This is my very long regex atm (which is basically glued together through groups according to the table above):

```js
/^(([A-Za-z&*@\^}\]\\):,$=!><–{[(%+#;\/~_?.]{1,3})|([a-z0-9&*@\^}\]\\):,$=!><–{[(%+#;\/~_?.]{1,4})|([A-Z0-9&*@\^}\]\\):,$=!><–{[(%+#;\/~_?.]{1,4})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4})|([a-z]{1,5})|([A-Z]{1,5})|([0-9]{1,7})|([&*@\^}\]\\):,$=!><–{[(%+#;\/~_?.]{1,5}))$/
```

Matches rows (above table): 12

```js
/([A-Za-z&*@\^}\]\\):,$=!><–{[(%+#;\/~_?.]{1,3})/
```

Matches rows:  14, 9

```js
/([a-z0-9&*@\^}\]\\):,$=!><–{[(%+#;\/~_?.]{1,4})/
```

Matches rows:  13, 10, 7

```js
/([A-Z0-9&*@\^}\]\\):,$=!><–{[(%+#;\/~_?.]{1,4})/
```

Matches rows:  11, 8, 6, 5

```js
/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4})/
```

Matches rows:  2

```js
/([a-z]{1,5})/
```

Matches rows:  1

```js
/([A-Z]{1,5})/
```

Matches rows:  3

```js
/([0-9]{1,7})/
```

Matches rows:  4

```js
/([&*@\^}\]\\):,$=!><–{[(%+#;\/~_?.]{1,5})/
```

Is there a way to reuse the special characters that I specified inside `[]` `[&*@\^}\]\\):,$=!><–{[(%+#;\/~_?.]`, so I don't have to write all of them inside every group ?

Comment: Password complexity != strength. It helps, but the biggest determining factor of password strength is entropy, or password length.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://www.xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: Make the first step and allow passwords without special signs but with a required length of 20+ chars. Also suggest using short phrases to make it easier for ppl to generate new passwords. And exclude "CorrectHorseBatteryStaple" from valid passwords :)

Comment: If your code works well and there is no issue, please consider posting the question at [codereview.se].

Comment: @evolutionxbox to elaborate, I'm building a simple JS random password generator that also informs the user about the strength of the generated password. The table above also takes in account the number of unique characters within the chosen options, so for numbers there are 10 unique characters and for ABC, abc, numbers, #$& there are 90. Therefore pwd like `0000000` is considered weak but `aA#9` is not. I'm a newbie when it comes down to security and just trying to better understand this problem.

Comment: https://howsecureismypassword.net/ says that the password `aA#9` could be cracked in _9 hundred microseconds_ by my laptop where as `birale vermoine` (a password I made up for this) would take _5 million years_ despite being only letters.

Comment: @evolutionxbox So if I understand correctly, adding an extra character to the password length has a much larger impact on the strength because it (more or less) creates exponentially more combinations to brute force. I also forgot to mention that I have 5 password strength indicators (very weak, ..., very strong), I just simplified it for the example. Based on [howsecureismypassword.net](http://howsecureismypassword.net), my passwords that I mark as very strong are in the years to crack.

Comment: I understand that to be the base of password authentication. As you pointed out even with long passwords, simple ones like `0000000` are still a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to reuse the special characters that I specified inside []...so I don't have to write all of them inside every group ?

Not with a regular expression literal, no.

You can do it with the `RegExp` constructor, though. You can mitigate the fact it wants a string by using `String.raw` so you don't have to worry about escaping backslashes:

```
const chars = String.raw`[the chars]`;
const rex = new RegExp(String.raw`^...${chars}...${chars}...$`);
```

You could take it further by creating a specific tag function for that, like this (this is an example from Chapter 10 of my new book; see my profile for details):

```
const createRegex = (template, ...values) => {
    // Build the source from the raw text segments and values
    const source = String.raw(template, ...values);
    // Check it's in /expr/flags form
    const match = /^\/(.+)\/([a-z]*)$/.exec(source);
    if (!match) {
        throw new Error("Invalid regular expression");
    }
    // Get the expression and flags, create
    const [, expr, flags = ""] = match;
    return new RegExp(expr, flags);
};
```

Then:

```
const chars = String.raw`[the chars]`;
const rex = createRegex`/^...${chars}...${chars}...$/`;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which regex engine you are using. However, if it is Perl or Ruby, you may use **subroutines** to achieve this **to a good extent**. Subroutines are repeating patterns within a regex.

You may be aware of backreferences. However, subroutines are different from backreferences. In the case of a backreference, the content of the captured group is matched and not the pattern. However, in the case of a subroutine, the pattern matching is repeated.

Let us take an example.

- Test string: `abcd-defg`
- Regex in **Ruby**: `/(?<dd>[a-z]+)-\g<dd>/`. The match will succeed.
- The `\g<dd>` part is the subroutine call in Ruby to the group named `dd`. (`\g<group_name>` is Ruby regex style. For the engine you are using, it may be different.)

More details here:

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html
- https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#named-subroutines

---

In your case, I think you can name each group when it appears the first time in the regex and then refer to it as a subroutine subsequently. Eg, let us call

- `[A-Z]` as `A`
- `[a-z]` as `a`
- `[0-9]` as `n`
- the special character set as `s` (Not sure if I got this pattern right.)

Then, **the pattern for 12** `/([A-Za-z&*@\^}\]\\):,$=!><–{[(%+#;\/~_?.]{1,3})/` becomes

```
/((\g<A>|\g<a>|\g<s>)){1,3})/
```

That is, `A OR a OR s repeated 1-3 times`.

And **the pattern for 11, 8, 6, 5** `/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4})/` becomes

```
/((\g<a>|\g<A>|\g<n>)){1,4})/
```

That is, `a OR A OR n repeated 1-4 times`.

Comment: I've updated my question (specified the regex flavor). I'm using the ECMAScript (JavaScript) flavor and it seems like the subroutines are not supported. I've quickly tested your first example with an online tool (regex101). Only the PCRE (PHP) flavor worked for me.

Comment: @htmn I think JavaScript doesn't support subroutines. :-( So, you will be left no option but to modularize your code with variables and then construct the final regex by concatenating them. Or you may try TJCrowder's method. (I am not familiar with that.)

Comment: *"I am not sure which regex engine you are using..."* All revisions of the question, including the first, are tagged [tag:javascript]. That tells you what engine @htmn is using.